# How can I save the input values of the stringfieldeditor of preference page?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created one preference page where there are stringfieldeditor.
Whenever user give some input on any fieldeditor,I want to save those in predference page class.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained pretty well [in the documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/preferences_prefs_implement.htm) look at the "Plugin preference store" section.